# Vuejs shorthand for conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

In Laravel I can use this shorthand:

```
{{ $my_variable ?? '-' }}
```

Instead:

```
{{ ($my_variable) ? $my_variable : '-' }}
```

Is there an equivalent in VueJS?

I'm doing this so far:

```
@{{ (my_var) ? my_var : '-' }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use *or logical operator* `||` :

```
@{{ my_var || '-' }}
```